# Extracting IP addresses from text file with batch

Tags: string, batch-file, trim

I have a text file with data like this:

Aug 21 [10.23.5.5] Teardown dynamic

Aug 18 [10.150.1.45] Aug 21 15:28:34 otoldc

Aug 24 [10.96.5.10] Aug 21 2012 18:58:26 HYD

Aug 24 [10.96.5.10] Aug 22 2012 18:58:26 HYD

Aug 21 [192.168.15.231] sendmail[18831]

I need to remove everything except IP addresses surrounded by "[" and "]". String length before "[" is fixed. String length after "]" varied.
I tried use one of existing solutions here but couldn't get success. Is it possible to do it using batch?
Thanks:-)

Answer (score 2):

directly from command line: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %F in (file.txt) do echo %F`. Redirect as you wish. 
Not as flexible as sed/awk & regexes, but it does not require external tools.

If you plan to put together something more complex though, I would really look to more powerful tools - apart from already mentioned awk or Perl natural choice on Win would be Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Install a version of `sed` if it's not already on your system.

```
$ sed -r -e 's/^[^[]*\[([^]\]*)].*/\1/' file.txt
10.23.5.5
10.150.1.45
10.96.5.10
10.96.5.10
192.168.15.231
```

This sed one-liner 'script' outputs each input line after removing everything from the lines except the contents inside the *first*  set of [] square brackets on the line - it does *not* check those contents to make sure it matches an IP address.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Will install sed and try it. Greatly appreciate :-)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as batch, so I assume this is on Windows and not linux. All the same, I'd highly recommend you head over to [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)'s website and download a copy. This will give you access to the `cat` and `grep` commands, which make this much simpler. Once you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you can run the following command to parse out the IP addresses from your log file.

`cat your.log | grep -oE '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' > ips.txt`

Cheers

Comment: `grep` won't extract the IP addresses, it will just output the matching lines.  You want `sed` or `awk` or similar to process the line.

Comment: I think the `>` and `>>` stdout redirect operators work on Windows, too.

Comment: ah, okay. I didn't spot that you'd used grep's `-o` (`--only-matching`) option.  redirection isn't really relevant, though.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Will install Cygwin and try it. Greatly appreciate it.